# How to extract data and return in c program

Tags: c

Assuming I have 3 columns of data below, how can I define the first column to be x and 2nd column to be y? 354560.50000 149632.50000 are the starting points of reference such that

```
lon = x - 354560.50000
lat = y - 149632.50000
```

and I can then calculate the distance using dist = sqrt(lon*lon + lat*lat) and if dist = a specific value, then extract the associated PL value in column 3?

```
    x              y              PL                          
354560.50000    149632.50000    -9999
354561.50000    149632.50000    -9999
354562.50000    149632.50000    -9999
354563.50000    149632.50000    106.50000
354564.50000    149632.50000    106.12500
354565.50000    149632.50000    106.25000
354566.50000    149632.50000    106.00000
354567.50000    149632.50000    -9999
```

```
have tried doing this but think it's not right.. 

#include<stdio.h>

int main()

{   int row=384;
    Int columns=256;
    FILE *pathloss;
    double dist, lon, lat, PL;

    
    //open file for reading
    pathloss=fopen("C:\\Users\\ISSuser\\Desktop\\PL_Site_1_1_107_100_M_Export.txt", "r");
    
    if (pathloss == NULL)
{
    puts(“error while opening file”);
    exit(1);
}
    lon = x - 354560.50000
    lat = y - 149632.50000
    

if (lon == 176 && lat == 159)
    
    while (Fscanf (pathloss ,"%*lf %*lf %lf", &lon, &lat, &PL) == 3);  

        Printf (“%f”, n3);

        fclose(pathloss);

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: int main()

{ int row=384;
 Int columns=256;
 FILE *pathloss;
 double dist, long, lat, PL;


 //open file for reading
 pathloss=fopen("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\PL_Site_1_1_107_100_M_Export.txt", "r");
 
 if (pathloss == NULL)
{
 puts(“error while opening file”);
 exit(1);
}
 long = x - 354560.50000
 lat = y - 149632.50000 
 
 dist = sqrt(long*long + lat*lat)

 if (dist==distance2D)

 Fscanf (pathloss ,"%*f %*f %f",&n3) == Dist2D);  //suppress 1st and 2nd colummn

  Printf (“%f”, n3);

  fclose(pathloss);

  return 0;
 }

Comment: dont copy the code in comment section it will be difficult to read, instead edit your original post

Comment: i see.. thanks ! will take note of tt cos realised the formatting went haywire..

Comment: @Noobiee when you edit your question, please don't mess up my edits.

Comment: those will be replaced by code i guess :)

Comment: The code in comment would not compile. When you post the code please make sure it is the [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that demonstrates the problem, that is, *real* code that can be compiled and tested. Copy/paste is the way to do this, to avoid typos. You might benefit by reading the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding. Maybe based on the original post, do you have any suggestion how i could go about doing it ?

Comment: @Noobiee please [edit] your question and post your code _there_

Comment: Note: you can't use the standard type name `long` as an identifier.

Comment: `while(fscanf(pathloss, "%lf%lf%lf", &lon, &lat, &PL) == 3) { /* process data */ }` But I might actually use `fgets()` and `sscanf()`. This makes it easy to skip the headings line and stay line-oriented.

Comment: Your code does not compile, there are multiple errors. Is _that_ the problem you're asking about?

Comment: hi all, i wanted to do the following (1) how to define 1st column as x, 2nd column as y and 3rd column as PL or just by labelling it in the .txt file will do? (2) i need to apply the formula for each row of data to obtain the longitude and latitude i.e. longitude = x - 354560.50000 and latitude = y - 149632.50000 (3) compute the dist via the sqrt formula and (4) if the dist == some value then extract the respective PL..

Comment: `long` is a type identifier and a reserved word in C.  You cannot call the longitude `long`.  Select another name.  Also, don't use `Int` as a synonim of `int`.  C is case sensitive and it's not the same `int` than `Int`.

Comment: thanks, have edited the codes.. but how do i code it such that it will scan through the rows of data and if there is a match, return the PL value associated in that row ?

Comment: hi, have made further edits to the codes.. does it make sense ? Any advice is deeply appreciated..

Comment: it's ```printf``` and not ```Printf```